# Getting connections without requesting webpage

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to integrate socket.io on my webpage.

As soon as I boot up the script, the console is flooded with "Socket connected" messages, without me ever actually going to the webpage.

This is my code for loading socket.io:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on('connection', socket => {
    console.log("Socket connected");
});
server.listen(3000);
```

I have updated all of my dependencies, I have also tried reinstalling them all.

The user agent of the requests is

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.75 Safari/537.36 NVIDIACEFClient/rel_03_19/82ba877 NVIDIAOSCClient/3.19.0.107
```

but I can't seem to find anything on the NVIDIACEFClient nor the NVIDIAOSCClient online.

The address of the requests is simply ::1

The only fix I have found thus far is to change the port, which I definitely do not find to be optimal, although it is the best I can do right now.

[image: Console after a few seconds looks like this]

Comment: Have you tried [running it in debug](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/web_development/9781785880865/1/ch01lvl1sec14/debugging-on-the-server)? Or collecting logs somehow (for example, to inspect who is the issuer of these connections).

Comment: @MarekPiotrowski I updated my post with a bit more information

Comment: It might have to do something with your environment. In your code sample, http instantiation is missing, but I assume it's `const http = require('http');`. Besides that, I added `server.listen` with simple console.log, but no clients connect "automatically" after running the script. On which port does your application listen? Maybe you do something with `http`?

Comment: @MarekPiotrowski My application is listening on port 3000. I am not doing anything with http except for instantiating it (I have updated my code to include that).

Comment: I believe this one sounds like it: https://superuser.com/questions/1448490/how-to-find-source-of-traffic-to-socket-io-on-win-10-desktop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, basing on the issuer of these connections, it appears that it's due to your environment. After a quick googling, it appears you have to turn off the **In Game Overlay** feature in NVIDIA GeForce Experience, as per [this](https://superuser.com/a/1457943) answer.

I'd add my two cents, though. You'd avoid all the debugging if you ran your application in an isolated environment, eg. Virtual Machine (maybe docker would be enough, not sure). This is also why a Continuous Integration environment is desirable - you'd see right away that on CI machine everything works fine, unlike on your local PC with some particular environment.